# How to repeat function within same programme

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment I have this function:

```
from oracle import Oracle
oracle = Oracle()
import random

def highlow(tolerance):
    """Returns approximation of a randomly generated number between
    1-100 to within a given tolerance"""
    b = [0, 100]
    guess = random.random()*100  # random starting guess
    while abs(oracle.reveal() - guess) > tolerance:
        if oracle.ask(guess) is True: # guess is less than number
            b[0] = guess # guess becomes new lower bound
            guess = (guess + b[1])/2 # guess is middle of new range
        else: # guess is larger or equal
            b[1] = guess # guess becomes new upper bound
            guess = (guess + b[0])/2 # guess is middle of new range
    return b
```

Within the same programme I would like to run this function 3 times with different numbers generated by the oracle, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you initialize the function you're running it again. You'd just do:

> first_run = highlow(YOUR_NUMBER)
>
> second_run = highlow(ANOTHER_NUMBER)

Etc.. as you need to.

Comment: It runs the function again, but the oracle module does not generate a new number, this is what I need to happen.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! This is because you're assigning the value of Oracle to oracle outside the function. Simply move: oracle = Oracle() into the first line of your function.